# Append Radio Button Value on Page Load

Tags: javascript, jquery, forms, append

I am using a e-commerce solution where I have to pass a sub_end_date to the form checkout. The end date has to be dynamically generated on page load.

i.e. If a customer orders a 6 month subscription on 20130101 so we have set the sub_enddate=20130601.

I can't get my jquery code to work. I am trying to append the value of id="6mths" and id="12mths" on page load to add the date 6 and 12 months from now. The for id="6mths"s value to be "name=6mths&sub_enddate=(6months from today in YYYYMMDD)" and id="12mths"s value to be "name=12mths&sub_enddate=(12months from today in YYYYMMDD)"

```
var end_date_6mths = new Date();
end_date_6mths.setMonth(end_date_6mths.getMonth() + 6);
sub_enddate_6mths = end_date_6mths.getFullYear() + padWithZero(end_date.getMonth() + 1) + padWithZero(end_date.getDate());
jQuery("input[id=6mths]").val(sub_enddate_6mths);


var end_date_12mths = new Date();
end_date_12mths.setMonth(end_date_12mths.getMonth() + 12);
sub_enddate_12mths = end_date_12mths.getFullYear() + padWithZero(end_date_12mths.getMonth() + 1) + padWithZero(end_date_12mths.getDate());
jQuery("input[id=12mths]").val(sub_enddate_12mths);
```

http://jsfiddle.net/hVzRn/

Answer (score 0):

`end_date` is not defined :

```
var end_date_6mths = new Date();
end_date_6mths.setMonth(end_date_6mths.getMonth() + 6);
sub_enddate_6mths = end_date_6mths.getFullYear() + padWithZero(end_date.getMonth() + 1) + padWithZero(end_date.getDate());
jQuery("input[id=6mths]").val(sub_enddate_6mths);
```

To

```
var end_date_6mths = new Date();
end_date_6mths.setMonth(end_date_6mths.getMonth() + 6);
sub_enddate_6mths = end_date_6mths.getFullYear() + padWithZero(end_date_6mths .getMonth() + 1) + padWithZero(end_date_6mths .getDate());
jQuery("input[id=6mths]").val(sub_enddate_6mths);
```

To debug javascript, use the developer console of your browser, accessible with F12 key on FF, Chrome and IE.

Comment: Thanks. I made that change and have been using the console but I still can't get it working.

Comment: Works ok for me on jsFiddle, i obtain "20140512" value for the first radio and "2037" for the second. I guess you haven't finished your string building yet, isn't it ?

Comment: Yeah I still need to add some paramaters to the URL. The 12 month result isn't what I am looking for. Do you know how I can change the padWithZero so the 12mth value = 2013(12 months from today)?